# How to refer to this method of mixing solids?

Tags: home-experiment, mixtures

The steps of this process are:

1. Fill a container with water (or other solvent)
2. Add mixants (is that the right word?) the container
3. Stir until all mixants are dissolved/suspended
4. Boil off the water (or other solvent)

The substances do not end up chemically reacting during this process. A real-world application of this is in small-scale manufacture of Rocket Candy, where this is used to mix KNO3 and Sucrose so the mixture can later be ignited and will burn more smoothly. Another example is making a cake - all the ingredients end up dissolved or suspended in the batter to mix them, and then the water is boiled off during baking. (Yes, there are also a lot of other things that happen during cake-making.)

What is the name of this process, if it has one? If not, what is a succinct way to describe it or state that this is what is used?

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest term would be recrystalisation though this is normally used to dissolve one component (the desired one) to allow the removal of impurities, so I would be hesitant to use it but it is used here to describe the rocket candy example you used: http://www.jamesyawn.net/rcandy/index.htm

With regards to your second example, baking a cake is actually a series of interesting and complex chemical reactions and structural changes. The New Zealand institute of chemistry wrote a nice summary of the chemistry of baking that can be found here: http://nzic.org.nz/ChemProcesses/food/6D.pdf

Hope that helps